# Is it possible to know default size of the QML Control?

Tags: qml, qt6

Is it possible to know default size (height) of the QML Control? Something like `QWidget::sizeHint()`...

I want to set `implicitHeight` of the `TextField` to be 8mm, this is fine on desktops, but on Android 8mm is not enough, so I want something like:

```
implicitHeight: Math.max( minimumCtrlHeight (8mm), defaultHeight )
```

Maybe this can be done with another approach? Thanks.

Maybe in QML it's possible to use something like `#ifdef` to set `implicitHeight` on desktops but not on mobile?

Comment: don't set size at all and that probably will be a default one

Comment: Yes, it will be default size, but on desktop it's a small one, it's just a line of text somewhere 10pt, but I want controls to be with min height 8mm. I need to use `implicitHeight`, but on Android with default style it's not enough.

Comment: You can Use `Qt.platform.os`

Comment: Sure, and what should be set `implicitHeight` on non-desktops?

Comment: @IgorMironchik Use "@" to notify..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Rectangle {
    id: root
    anchors.centerIn: parent;
    function preffredButtonHeight(parent_: Item) {
        if (Qt.platform.os == "android" || 
               Qt.platform.os == "wasm" || 
               Qt.platform.os == "ios") {
            return Math.max(parent_.height / 25, 88, implicitHeight);
        } else {
            return Math.max(parent_.height / 25, 50, implicitHeight);
        }
    }
    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent;
        text: "platform is: " + Qt.platform.os
        height: preffredButtonHeight(parent)
    }
}
```

This could be done more declaratively though I think it would be more messy.
You can also implement that JS function in C++, That is what I would do.

Note that you can use `Screen.desktopAvailableHeight` if you don't want to use `parent` or use both of them them...

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Rectangle {
    id: root
    anchors.centerIn: parent;
    function preffredButtonHeight(parent_: Item) {
        if (Qt.platform.os == "andriod" || "wasm" || "ios") {
            return Math.max(Screen.desktopAvailableHeight / 25, 88, implicitHeight);
        } else {
            return Math.max(Screen.desktopAvailableHeight / 25, 50, implicitHeight);
        }
    }
    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent;
        text: "platform is: " + Qt.platform.os
        height: preffredButtonHeight(parent)
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case `height: Math.max( appWindow.minimumCtrlHeight, implicitHeight )` works well, I even don't need to use function. Thanks.